# getAllWindowTitles method in Selenium 2 behaving differently

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, webdriver

I'm trying to get my old Selenium RC tests to function with Selenium 2.0b2 standalone.  I'm using the Selenium python driver and have not gone with the approach of running weddriver and selenium tests side by side with the WebDriverBackSelenium.  This maybe the approach but thats a separate question.  So I'm faced with a problem of getting Selenium 2 to work with Firefox 3 & 4.  Here is a sample of my test:

```
sel.open("window.html")
 sel.click("ff4button")
 for i in range(60):
    windowname = sel.get_all_window_titles()
    print windowname
```

The only window this ever finds is the parent window in this case called Base window, here is the source of the 2 HTML files

The window.html source is this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Base window</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function openwindow()
{
    window.open("test.html", "testwindow", "width=500,height=500");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Firefox 4 Selenium sample</h1>
<button id="ff4button" onclick="openwindow()">Open new window</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Which opens test.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>testwindow</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>New Window</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyone have ideas on why this isn't seeing the new window opened.  This is a showstopper for me at least running Selenium 2.0b2 until i can migrate my tests to webdriver.

Comment: Apparently this is because Selenium 2 is not officially certified to execute tests on Firefox 4, that is not to say tests will not run in Firefox 4.  But interaction between windows and not using WebDriver will cause problems

Comment: Selenium 2.0b3 is out which supports FF4, you can try it

Comment: Yea it works partially, the function get_all_window_titles finds the opened window, but the name is incorrect.  I may have to refactor my tests to get all window titles and select the last window, which is a safe assumption in my part, but hoping they fix this in beta 4

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem you're having is a variation of http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1441 and a bunch of other similar bugs - which are likely fixed in Selenium 2.0rc2.